# How to move a ImageButton dynamically?

Tags: android, imagebutton

I'm new to Android

I need to move the ImageButton dynamically, Like when i click the button it needs to be relocated into a new position. Im using AbsoluteLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never ever use AbsoluteLayouts. Use animations instead. imageView.startAnimation(ANIMATION); You can find examples from google [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/index.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)

Comment: Hey, I was wondering, how can I make the image button move around so that it looks as if it's vibrating? For example, the way Apple apps move when you hold them down to delete them? I have been searching this for a few hours with no luck, I really appreciate your help!