# Change position of an ImageButton programmatically

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have an Imagebutton and I would like to move it according to an imaginary line:

[image]

How would I go about doing something like this?

Comment: Did you come across [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5180837/1101070) question in your research? What have you tried thus far?

Comment: I know how to make a simple animation using tweening in XML, usually it's for straight lines.. But I'm tring to figure out if there is a better way to doing it when the line is like the attached above

Comment: Did you figure it out? I was wondering, how can I make the image button move around so that it looks as if it's vibrating? For example, the way Apple apps move when you hold them down to delete them? I have been searching this for a few hours with no luck, I really appreciate your help!